# Bypassing popup blocker in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<a href = "#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
```

I have an onclick even handler that when the link above is clicked, calls window.open. That works in Chrome but not in Safari. How do I get it to work in Safari?

```
$('fb').on('click', function () {
   window.open();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the user has pop-ups blocked, there will be no way to "bypass" this.  Given your code, try

```
<a href="#" class="fb" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

instead, for setting the target should also open the link in a new window/tab.