# Safari blocking popups

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, twitter

I have a twitter sign in, it's known that Google and Facebook have their own **script for opening sign in popup** and it somehow works even on Safari, but twitter doesn't. So we implemented our own, the issue we face is that IOS devices are blocking popup opened with:

```
 window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=400,width=800,left=250,top=100,resizable=yes', true);
```

I've also tried creating an anchor tag after reading ([Bypassing popup blocker in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018260/bypassing-popup-blocker-in-safari)):

```
 <a id="js__twitter__popup-link" target="_blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
```

Then we **add url to href** `this.twitterPopupLink.setAttribute('href', url)`, then `document.querySelector("#js__twitter__popup-link").click()`, but on IOS it won't open a new page even that way.

Tester said that on iPad popup is opened but using IOS emulators it didn't open for me on iPad. It's a sure thing that it doesn't open popup on **iPhone** through.

Answer (score 8):

> on IOS it won't open a new page even that way

Correct. The point of a popup blocker is to prevent popups. Any workaround you can imagine they've probably also imagined and prevented.

In general, you can only open a popup window in one scenario - immediately after a **user-initiated** click. Triggering a click via JavaScript won't bypass this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand, still, somehow Facebook and Google solved the issue without additional clicks from the user.

Comment: Facebook and Google's OAuth login buttons both require a user click in the web SDK. If you're referring to the iOS SDK, they'll be triggering it natively, not in Safari.

Comment: We also implemented Facebook and Google sign-in, two additional buttons, but there once you click on the button the popup is opened, it seems now that for twitter I'll need to make the user click twice(at least on IOS).

Comment: No, you don't need two clicks. Just stop trying to *fake* the click. Make a button that has an `onclick` that calls your `window.open` code. It just has to be synchronous and user-initiated.

Comment: The twitter button is a web component, component listens to the click, on click makes a call to the back-end to get twitter token using consumer API keys (which are stored in a config file), after receiving response client tries to open twitter popup using twitter URL with params.

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps it would help if you linked us to the exact component you're using. If it's your own, open the popup immediately onclick, and do the call to the backend via AJAX *in* the popup.

Comment: @Daniel In that case, I'd take the approach from my last comment - open the popup immediately, and make the server-side calls *within* the popup.

Comment: But how you make server-side calls within popup? On first click popup doesn't exist, then it sends a URL with some params then as the response you get a popup page right? Then how you execute the script inside it? Detect when the popup is received and insert script inside it ?

Comment: You open a popup to a page on your server. You make an AJAX call on that page, then redirect once it finishes.